# Installing Petsc from source, Specified destDir same as current PETSC_DIR/PETSC_ARCH

Tags: macos, unix, makefile, petsc

I'm doing my best to install petsc from source. Here's what I did:

```
$ git clone -b maint https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc petsc
$ cd petsc/
$ pwd
/Users/kilojoules/install_petsc/petsc
$ export PETSC_DIR=/Users/kilojoules/install_petsc/petsc
$ make 
   # everything runs fine
$ make install
*** Using PETSC_DIR=/Users/kilojoules/install_petsc/petsc PETSC_ARCH=arch-darwin-c-debug ***
********************************************************************
Incorrect prefix usage. Specified destDir same as current PETSC_DIR/PETSC_ARCH
********************************************************************
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. The [Petsc documentation](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/installation.html) says nothing about specifying a destination directory. When I do `make all`, it promps me to do a `make test`, which prompts me to do a `make streams`, which doesn't prompt me to do anything else. How can I finish installing this package from source? Is there a way to specify the install destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set a destination directory, use a prefix. Otherwise, `mae install` doesn't make sense because you already installed it in the destination directory.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/petsc
make all
make install
```